# Anylogic. Need to count the average Rating of Adopters

Tags: java, anylogic

I need to count average rate of product by adopters. I have a stock Adopters and dynamic variable Rate with function `(uniform (1,5))` inside it. I can use only stocks, dynamic and usual variables and flows.

I made dynamic variable Ratesumm for count all rate value together.

```
Ratesumm = Ratesumm + Rate;
```

Then I'll divide it to Adopters. Also I made dynamic variables AmountRate and Opinion with `if-else` construction for counting this:

```
Opinion = ((Adopters == 0)? Opinion : 0 ;
(Adopters == AmountRate && Adopters > 0)? Opinion : (Ratesumm / Adopters))
```

But Ratesumm doesn't count total value ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igTQ4.png)). What should i do? Maybe there is another way to count average rate?

Comment: Wow maybe you can write the right formula for amount calculation then??